# if (isset($var)) { } difficulty using isset

Tags: php, sql, isset

having difficulty using if (isset('prescription')) {'prescription'} in the below code:

```
$query = " 
    SELECT 
        id, 
        full_name,
        address,
        email,
        telephone,
        prescription
    FROM patients 
    WHERE id 
    LIKE '%" . $patient_id . "%'";
```

problem is that whenever php fetches results from table fields, prescription is sometimes null and sometimes with info.. therefore this notice shows up: Notice: Undefined index:

the solutions I'm finding only portray using isset on form inputs rather on data originating from tables. therefore the found examples contain $_POST or $_GET , which don't work for me.

cheers,
Iain

Comment: I don't see you using `isset('prescription')` in the code you provided.  Also, `Notice: Undefined index` usually refers to an array and I don't see you using an array here either.

Comment: You use isset() to test if variables are set, not hard-coded strings: `if (isset('prescription')) {'prescription'}` is meaningless

Comment: **Read. Learn. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection**

Comment: I'm assuming the error is coming from the result of a fetch and around a line like `echo $row['prescription']`. You need to show that code to help identify the problem. Also, even if a DB column value is `NULL`, the fetched array index should still be set so I'm guessing you're attempting this on an empty result set

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess you're attempting to read a value from an empty result set. You should be checking for a valid result first. Here's an example using PDO

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

// I've changed your query to remove the LIKE comparison
// Seemed incorrect for an ID lookup
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT
    id, full_name, address, email, telephone, prescription
    FROM patients WHERE id = ?');

$stmt->bindParam(1, $patient_id);
$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Check for any results
if (0 === count($results)) {
    throw new Exception('No results found');
}

foreach ($results as $result) : ?>

<dl>
    <dt>ID</dt>
    <dd><?= htmlspecialchars($result['id']) ?></dd>

    <dt>Full name</dt>
    <dd><?= htmlspecialchars($result['full_name']) ?></dd>

    <!-- and so on -->
</dl>

<?php endforeach ?>
```